# Java Mission Control 7.1 shows too few method profiling samples

Tags: jfr, java-mission-control

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395700/java-mission-control-says-few-profiling-samples-why-and-what-are-my-other-op).

I'm profiling an Open JDK 11.0.2 application using JMC 7.1.0 which I've built according to the [instructions](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=947).

The application is utilizing about 3 cores, there is no excessive gc and only a small portion of the time threads are doing native method calls that actually utilize CPU.

I'm using the default method sampling interval of 10ms.
I enabled debug meta data outside of safepoints by using:

-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints

The number of samples taken is much less then I expect.
Assuming conservatively that there is 1 on cpu thread running non native code at each sampling point, I would expect 100 samples / second. Yet I'm seeing only 1 sample / second.

[image: cpu usage & method samples]

The machine itself is usually 50% idle, so the sampling thread is not starved.

What can be causing the number of samples to be that low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to a bug introduced in JDK 11 which appear in applications with many threads. It has been fixed in JDK 12 and backported to 11.0.3.

For details see:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215727

Regarding the sampling interval. The default rate is 20 ms, but it doesn't mean there will be 50 samples / seconds. It is the interval the JVM tries to samples one or **more** threads.